# I'm getting this error message and understand why: cannot be applied to given types; required: no augments found: int, int

Tags: java

This may be a lack of sleep situation but I cannot figure out why I'm getting this message, I know it'll be a simple fix but I cannot wrap my head around it, any help is appreciated.

For context, I'm trying to take the user's input and then plug that in and compare that to the values in a 2D array.

This is the array I'm trying to compare

```java
String[][] board = {{"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
    {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},{"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
    {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},{"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
    {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},{"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"},
    {"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"}};
```

```java
public void makeMove() {
    Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the row");
    int tempCol = choice.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Now the column");
    int tempRow = choice.nextInt();

    // a.setPiece(tempRow, tempCol, "W");
    a.isValid(tempRow, tempCol);
}
```

a.isValid is throwing out the error message:

```
method isValid in class board cannot be applied to given types;
    required: no arguments
    found: int, int
    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

And this is the method I'm trying to communicate with:

```java
public void isValid() {
    if (board[tempRow][tempCol] = "W") {
        display();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Move invalid, try again");
        makeMove();
    }
}
```

**This also throws out a different error message but I'm going to create a new question for that**

Comment: To add something further to all the answers, you also seem to have a class called "board" as well as an array called the same name. This is confusing.

Comment: Also, if you call a method "isXxxx", by convention that method should return a boolean, and you should use it in statements like `if (isXxxx(...))...`. Your isValid method returns void. Either rename it (maybe `validate()`?) or use it in an if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

isValid() does not have any parameters declared, but your are passing two ints. Did you mean to declare it like this?

```
public void isValid(int tempRow, int tempCol){
    if(board[tempRow][tempCol] = "W"){
        display();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Move invalid, try again");
        makeMove();
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew it was simple but I was hoping for it to be at least a little more complicated than that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your `isValid` method doesn't take any arguments, but you try to pass it 2 `int`s anyways. You'll have to change your declaration to say:

```
public void isValid(int tempRow, int tempCol){
```

That way it can actually take your `int`s and process them.